# How do I keep the rear wheel axle assembly from rotating on a Sun Joe electric mower?

Tags: lawn-mower

I have a Sun Joe 48-Volt 17-in Push Cordless Electric Lawn Mower. It has height adjustment which allows you to raise it to a 3 inch cut. The rear assembly that adjust the wheels broke off and I am attempting to fix it so that the rear wheels are locked in the highest position because I never used the lower settings. I can’t come up with a way to lock it in place without the axel and wheels spinning and falling into the lowest position. Any ideas on how to do this? [image][image] the top picture is the position I want to lock it in.

Comment: Imagine the piece with the hole is what held it in place.  Should be able to make something that will attach to at least one of the screws on the wheel and that piece.

Comment: I wanted more height on my sunjoe, so I wrapped the wheels with packing foam and gorilla tape. The lines on the mowed lawn are softer to boot. Bigger wheels would work too. I fear a jimmy fix will break even sooner than the OEM part did...

Answer (score 1):

Big glob of epoxy (stiff putty or modified with "microbaloons" mixed in, not runny liquid) on both sides to lock up the rotation. If the strut with a hole in it was part of the adjustment, epoxy it in place as well to help brace it. Wiring the two parts together might also help.

Hot glue is also a (more removable) option.